# RestRoute that allows periods in id and accepts result format

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, rest

I have a heavily used REST service based on asp.net mvc. One of the resources is for users where you specify a given user with a route like this:

```
.../User/{id}.{format}
```

Ex:

```
http://mysvc.com/User/abc123.json
```

The id in this case is a username. We currently have a route map that accepts all characters but periods so as not to cause a conflict with the [optional] format extension.

Routemap:

```
/User/{id[^\\.]+}
```

Well, now we have a new client that uses email address as their username. This obviously causes an issue. We have considered eliminating the format extension support as all known clients currently use json. However, I would prefer not to do this and modify my route to accept the format or json or xml and still allow periods.

I feel there should be a way to format this regex so as to say the id may contain periods and still map the format if it is provided. However, I am currently having a mental block.

Comment: (.*?)\.json or ((?:.(?!\.json))*) might work